# Google keywords that lead them to the page

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to find out that the Google search was that lead them to the page was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `document.referrer` will tell you the URL of where the user came from. You can analyze the URL for what search terms were used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should look into [Google Analytics](http://www.google.ca/analytics/).

Comment: I want to include the keywords in an email, at the moment it's adding the referrer url.